# Relations between ordered pairs.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am completely confused about this question, everytime I look back onto it I have a different idea on how to interpret it. Any help is appreciated.

A relation $\mathit R$ is defined on $\mathbb Q^2$ by $(a,b) \mathit R (c,d)$ if and only if there exists a real number $x\geq1$ such that $a=dx$ and $c=bx$.

I need to show what type of relation this is, e.g. is it reflexive, transitive, symmetric....?
Right now, I am just having a lot of trouble on how to interpret this and how to actually come up with a way of proving this.

Comment: Try writing down the definitions of reflexive, transitive etc. and see how they apply to your $R$. E.g., , $R$ is reflexive iff $(a, b)R(a, b)$ for every $a, b \in \Bbb{Q}$: is that true?

Answer (score 0):

$(a,b){\in}\Bbb Q$ exactly when $a \in \Bbb Z\land b \in \Bbb Z{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$ ... a rational number is a pair of integers with the second member being non-zero. This pair is more often written as a ratio: $\tfrac ab$.

Your relation is defined as, $\mathop R:=\big\{((a,b),(c,d))\in \Bbb Q^2:\exists x\in \Bbb R_{\geq 1}~(a=xd\land c=xb)\big\}$

That is that two rational numbers are R-related when there is some real number (call it $x$) at least as great as one where $a=xd$ and $c=xb$.

---

$R$ will be reflexive exactly when $\forall (a,b){\in}\Bbb Q~({(a,b)}\mathop R{(a,b)})$ .  So is it true that $\exists x{\in}\Bbb R_{\geq 1}~(a=xb\land a=xb))$ for *every* rational $(a,b)$ ? (Yes / No)

Likewise use the definitions for symmetry and transitivity to investigate whether they hold for the relation.

Comment: What would happen in the case that a = 0? Since there is no value of x > 1 that would make x*b = 0 given that b is a non zero. Would this mean that the relation is not reflexive?

Comment: Indeed, @YusufBideen , a counterexample such as $(0,1)$ is a witness that $\exists (a,b)\in\Bbb Q~\lnot\exists x\in\Bbb R_{\geqslant 1}~(a=xb)$, thus disproving reflexivity of the relation.